# how to reduce the current without changing voltage for charging a 9 v battery

Tags: charging

I have some rechargeable ni-mh 9v batteries  (all 200mah) laying around and a 9v adapter with current output of 210ma... I know that 9 v batteries require 1/10th of its capacity to be charged (ie 20ma)...So ,is there a way to reduce the current output without reducing the voltage (maybe with some kind of resistors in series) so that i can charge these batteries safely??

thanks in advance

edit:
i have found some circuits online ..will this work??

1.[image]

2.[image]

Comment: If the battery will electrically accept more than the desired 20 mA at the present voltage across its terminals, then reducing that current necessarily means reducing the applied voltage.  A good charger would use a current regulating circuit for that phase of operation.  But detecting end-of-charge is more critical, and not a simple thing for NiMH cells in isolation, let alone 6 or 7 in series.  It's probably better to buy a solution than make your own, unless your goal is not to charge this battery but rather to invest in developing engineering expertise in this area.

Comment: I have found some circuits online which i have added to my question.....can anyone tell me if that will work??

Answer (score 2):

Your AC adapter is *rated* at 210mA, but it will try to deliver whatever current the load demands. Rechargeable batteries will take very high current if you let them, so some form of current limiting is essential. You may be able to regulate the charging current with a resistor. *However* whether it will work and what resistance value you need depends on the specifics of your AC adapter.

A typical '9V' rechargeable PP9 battery consists of 7 NiMH cells in series. These have a nominal voltage 1.2V each, so the whole battery is actually only 1.2 x 7 = 8.4V. However when charging the voltage will go up to ~10V (1.4V per cell).

[image]

When using a resistor to regulate current the power supply must put out a *higher* voltage than the battery, which the resistor then drops down at a current determined by its value and the voltage drop across it. If your adapter's output is regulated to exactly 9V then its voltage is too low and the resistor won't work. However if it is unregulated then it may put out 12V or more at low current, which the resistor can then drop down to the 9~10V that the battery needs.

So what you need to do is *measure* the voltage coming out of your AC adapter, then calculate the resistor value required based on the difference between that and the battery voltage. For example from 12V to 9V the difference is 3V, so to keep the charging current below 20mA the resistance required would be 3V/20mA = 150Ω.

As the battery charges up its voltage increases, so the voltage drop and charging current reduces. At full charge the battery reaches ~10V for a difference of only 2V (with a 12V supply), so the charging current would drop to ~2V/150Ω = 13mA. This is good because it is kinder on the battery than continuing to charge it at the maximum rate.

Comment: So it will better if I use a 12v adapter and resistor in series?

Comment: If you are not able to _measure_ your adapter's output voltage then yes, a regulated 12V adapter would be safest because you know it's putting out 12V. If you have a multimeter then you can use any AC/DC adapter that puts out enough voltage (preferably >=12V) and simply adjust the resistor value to get the current you want.

Comment: Yes u are right..I don't have a multimeter :) I will try to do what u said ..and thank u for spending some time here :)

Answer (score -2):

Resistors in series would drop the voltage. Instead you can connect a resistor in parallel that can draw 180mA of current while allowing 20mA to charge the battery.

Comment: A resistor in parallel with a current source and one in series with a voltage source are duals of each other - **they have exactly the same behavior**.  In a real system such as this, which might work better would depend on the regimes where the unspecified charger acts more like a voltage vs a current source and the load the battery provides at different levels of charge.  Generally a resistor solution can only be tuned for one state of charge, how far off it is at others depends on details we don't have.

Comment: Also, we don't know that the power supply is current limited. It may be capable of supplying far more current even if the voltage starts to collapse.

Comment: I have found some circuits online which i have added to my question.....can anyone tell me if that will work??     i have found another one here!!! http://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/switchless-nicd-nimh-battery-charger_20.html

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should just connect a few of them in parallel and then charge them with your adapter. That way the current is divided amongst them.

Comment: It will require > 9 V to charge a 9 V NiCd battery. Paralleling batteries is a bad idea. The battery with the lowest voltage or lowest cell chemistry voltage will hog the current. When connected up as you have suggested any charged batteries will discharge into the flat battery.

Comment: I have found some circuits online which i have added to my question.....can anyone tell me if that will work??